# Is svn merge tracking possible in this situation?

Tags: svn, merge

TrunkA   TrunkB---->BranchB

I have a branchB created from TrunkB. I want to merge changes from TrunkA into my branch and commit it to TrunkB. Is there a way to use SVN merge tracking in this situation?

TrunkA is a subset of TrunkB but for some reason when I use "svn mergeinfo", it says they are not ancestrally related, even though I am able to merge TrunkA changes to my branch with no problem.

Comment: *"I want to merge changes from TrunkA into my branch and commit it to TrunkB."* You mean you want to merge changes from TrunkA into BranchB and then merge BranchB back into TrunkB? You can't commit from a branch into trunk. *"TrunkA is a subset of TrunkB"* Where did TrunkA come from? Was it created with `svn cp`? This seems like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)...why do you have two trunks?

Comment: Sorry, by branchB i mean a working copy of TrunkB. TrunkA is an open source repository that gets frequently updated and I want to merge those changes into TrunkB.

Comment: Okay, and how is TrunkB related to TrunkA? You say "TrunkA is a subset of TrunkB," but I don't know what that means. Was TrunkA created something like `svn cp TrunkB/some/subdir TrunkA`?